# Adding new columns in a dataframe gives length mismatch error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

From a csv file (`initial.csv`):

```
"Id","Name"
1,"CLO"
2,"FEV"
2,"GEN"
3,"HYP"
4,"DIA"
1,"COL"
1,"EOS"
4,"GAS"
1,"AEK"
```

I am grouping by the `Id` column and agreggating the `Name` column values so that each unique `Id` has all the `Name` values appended on the same row (`new.csv`):

```
"Id","Name"
1,"CLO","COL","EOS","AEK"
2,"FEV","GEN"
3,"HYP"
4,"DIA","GAS"
```

Now some rows have extra name values for which I want to append corresponding columns according the maximum count of `Name` values that exist on the rows, i.e.

```
"Id","Name","Name2","Name3","Name4"
1,"CLO","COL","EOS","AEK"
2,"FEV","GEN"
3,"HYP"
4,"DIA","GAS"
```

I do not understand **how I can add new columns on dataframe** to match the data.

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('initial.csv', delimiter=',')

max_names_count = 0
for id in unique_ids_list:
    mask = df['ID'] == id
    names_count = len(df[mask])
    if names_count > max_names_count:
        max_names_count = names_count

group_by_id = df.groupby(["Id"]).agg({"Name": ','.join})

# Create new columns 'Id', 'Name', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4'
new_column_names = ["Id", "Name"] + ['Name' + str(i) for i in range(2, max_names_count+1)]  

group_by_id.columns = new_column_names  #  <-- ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 5 elements
group_by_id.to_csv('new.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("initial.csv")

df_out = (
    df.groupby("Id")["Name"]
    .agg(list)
    .to_frame()["Name"]
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns=lambda x: "Name" if x == 0 else "Name{}".format(x + 1))
    .reset_index()
)
df_out.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Creates `out.csv`:

```
Id,Name,Name2,Name3,Name4
1,CLO,COL,EOS,AEK
2,FEV,GEN,,
3,HYP,,,
4,DIA,GAS,,
```

Comment: To help my understanding, could you please explain to me what the issue with my code was? Did I have to use `rename(Columns ...` followed by resetting the index as shown in your response?

Comment: @Yannis This `group_by_id.columns = new_column_names` won't work. `group_by_id` has only one column and you're trying to set more columns.

Comment: Just to help me understand your solution, could you please adapt it on my code so that I can see at which point I need to change? Your one line command with the lambda and all the other arguments really confuses me.